# Android Developer documentation IntentService: Are we defining the same class twice?

Tags: java, android, android-service, intentservice

So I'm following this example in Android developers:
http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
Creating a background service with IntentService.
Note that we define the class `RSSPullService` in the first code example:

```
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        // Gets data from the incoming Intent
        String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
        ...
        // Do work here, based on the contents of dataString
        ...
    }
}
```

In the following page, Reporting Work Status:
http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html
**I'm confused, are we defining the same class again to get the status?**

```
public final class Constants {
    ...
    // Defines a custom Intent action
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION =
        "com.example.android.threadsample.BROADCAST";
    ...
    // Defines the key for the status "extra" in an Intent
    public static final String EXTENDED_DATA_STATUS =
        "com.example.android.threadsample.STATUS";
    ...
}
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {
...
    /*
     * Creates a new Intent containing a Uri object
     * BROADCAST_ACTION is a custom Intent action
     */
    Intent localIntent =
            new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION)
            // Puts the status into the Intent
            .putExtra(Constants.EXTENDED_DATA_STATUS, status);
    // Broadcasts the Intent to receivers in this app.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont get confused,
both the classes are same

First one is to show how we create a service extending IntentService

Then they gave a example to send data to this IntentService

At last they gave example to shows how the same IntentService is returning result back.

Second code is just another example they changed the content of old intent service class

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm sorry I'm not able to up vote yet.

Comment: it certainly does, the above answer came before your answer. but will up vote you when I'm granted the right to do so.

Comment: My answer was 1 min before above answer. But anyway its ok

Answer (score 1):

That's two separate examples, no need to define it twice, just use one definition. The code from first example (creating Intent Service) is just merged with code from Reporting Work example.

Comment: Seems they ran out out class names :-) , and the example in the zip file uses another different way of defining the same class. Sorry that I'm not able to up-vote yet.